# Клич "ура"

Tags: этимология

А вот интересно, междометие "ура" — это просто набор звуков или у него есть какой-то осмысленный корень?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По одной из версий, от нов.-в.-нем. hurrа "ура" от ср.-в.-нем. hurrā, которое связывают с hurren "быстро двигаться". По другой версии, заимств. из тюркск. urа "бей": urmak "бить". Использованы данные Толкового словаря русского языка с включением сведений о происхождении слов (2007) 
Любители задорновщины скажут, что произошло от слова "ра", которое означает солнце, и предлога "у", что в итоге значит "находиться у солнца", но такая теория не приветствуется лингвистами.